# What's the time complexity of Python built-in Function `all()`

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, time-complexity

How to know the time complexity of Python built-in Function `all()`?

I have tried these ways but found no answer.

1. searched on official complexity documentation, but found no answer.
2. Tried to find in Python source code. But I cannot find where the algorithm `all()`. This is the only file about `all()` I found.
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9T8Gd.png)

Comment: It consumes the entire iterable in the worst case, so the complexity seems to be `O(n)`

Comment: This may answer your question: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all

Comment: The builtin `all` function is implemented as [this C function](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.10.4/Python/bltinmodule.c#L310-L357) in CPython.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Definitionally `O(n)`. It has to check the truthiness of all the values provided until it finds a falsy value. It short-circuits (if it finds a single falsy value, it stops immediately and returns `False` without checking the rest of the input), so in many cases it won't do all the work, but if the input is in fact all truthy, it must, by definition, check all of them, doing `O(n)` work. Big-O doesn't care about the possibility of short-circuiting.

Comment: Assuming each iterated value can be computed in O(1).

Comment: @rici: Kind of a facile statement. `n` is the number of items. It would take a truly a pathological design to make computing the truthiness of an element depend on an uncachable computation involving some fraction of *all* the preceding elements, and that would be a function of the iterator items themselves, not an inherent feature of `all` (which itself is doing `O(n)` truthiness evaluations). You don't have to qualify "average case `dict` access is `O(1)`" with "but hashing itself is `O(n)` in the size of the hashed item", as that's unrelated to the relevant `n` (the size of the `dict`).

Comment: `all(has_two_prime_factors(i) for i in generate_values())` does not seem pathological to me. But the computation is not likely to be O(1) if the values generated are increasing.

Comment: @rici: Yes, but that's entirely unrelated to `all`. `all` is doing `O(n)` work. That work might in turn be `O(m)` or `O(m**2)` or whatever in terms of some other `m`, unrelated to `n`, but the mere increase in input size, as opposed to input values, increases the work done by `all` (which is just `for x in it: if not x: return False` followed by `return True` if the loop completes) strictly linearly. Much like the `dict` case; the hash might take more time to compute for big inputs, and different types might have non-`O(1)` equality check cost, but it's not related to the `dict` size.

Comment: That's not the pathological case I refer to in any event, since the mere number of inputs there does not affect runtime at all. The pathological case would be a generator that produces values that implement `__bool__` in terms of all the previously generated values (thereby making the actual boolean testing `all` does implicitly perform more work as a *direct* consequence of processing more values). Which is nuts; while it would technically make `all` strictly >`O(n)`, it's really a problem with passing a `O(n**2)` generator to `all`, which does `O(n)` tests on things that do `O(n**2)` work.

Comment: Ok, if that's your interpretation of the question, I agree. Personally, I normally include the cost of hashing and equality checks in the cost of using a dictionary; otherwise, it's hard to discuss the tradeoff of using an O(1) hash with non-optimal distribution leading to a non-constant collision cost, or a well-distributed but non-constant time hash leading to expected constant collision count. Or to compare hashtables with tries. But I recognise that your definition is also valid.

Comment: @rici: Gotcha. For the code as a whole that uses `all`, I'd describe it as a greater big-O in your case. But it would be a big-O of the product of the associated components, not of `all` itself. For your `has_two_prime_factors` case, the total cost might be the product of `all`'s `O(n)` work and `has_two_prime_factors`'s `O(m**0.5)` per-item work (note `n` vs. `m`) making the overall work `O(n * m ** 0.5)`; that's not the big-O of `all` (doubling `n` while keeping `m` unchanged would double the work, as you'd expect for `all` being `O(n)`), but it is the big-O of the code you wrote.

Comment: @rici looking at the reference C implementation, the algorithm is completely opaque as to what `iternext(it)`  or `PyObject_IsTrue(item)` as they are not within the scope of `all`.  It's a very straightforward loop iterating over every item of the input, with absolutely "zero knowledge" on how or what the input may in fact provide hidden time complexities (which would need to be factored in iff OP explicitly asked, but this was not the case as OP did not as for "time complexity of `all` + whatever", but they just really want to see the code to see what its general case big-O might be).

Comment: @rici [`all` doing around n^2 truth value tests](https://tio.run/##fU9BSgQxELz3K/qYqMgsXkTYkz9Qb4uEbJLZGcgkodNZ8GN@wIeNPbOiCwMWhHR30VXV5YOHnB4eC81zT3lCssnLN04lE6@dvFMAcNHWiq9uoK9PP8qI6ksolH1z0j1bfgIU@NCjMcecozGqhtjry3zB2P8JqnRFLHCW670tJSR/2ftlKXCjhG/UJAZT48GcbWzBcKhccY8dLK4ut8RKZH6ETzEfbcTNwkpuZW73uIMrOxECSKK@67oOlnRSH/65X@l3vMEENkY12aLWPHfrXVpDoVHSbWz1PH8D) on an input of length n :-)

Comment: @metatoaster: the C++ standard provides the following complexity requirement for `std::all`; I think it's a much clearer statement: "Complexity: At most `last - first` applications of the predicate and any projection." (`last` and `first` are indexes into the sequence). In Python, I would translate that to say the (worst-case) time complexity of `all(iter)` is the time complexity of  iterating `iter` and converting the elements to `bool`.

Comment: @kelly: nice example, although some might say that it's pussological.

Comment: @rici For many types, it doesn't convert to `bool`, for example for `None` it doesn't.

Comment: @rici which... there is a single operation to iter and there exists `n` conversions to `bool`.

Comment: @KellyBundy: Thank you for illustrating the point about it being *technically* possible to make `all` overall `O(n**2)` in terms of the same `n` (the length of the input), while also demonstratingly how "pussological" the code would have to be to behave that way. :-)

Comment: @kelly: it calls `PyObject_IsTrue()` on the object, which I would say is a conversion to bool, albeit trivial in many cases.

Comment: @rici Not to `bool` but to `int` (the C kind). [Source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/33880b4b1c60f54aa9e7fa02698a3c82eafe3dc7/Objects/object.c#L1491).

Comment: @ShadowRanger I was indeed kidding, but now that I think about it, [this](https://tio.run/##TYxBCsIwEEX3nmKWzaYIbkTQi4iU6ExoIMzE6aTU08emLupbft77@WOj8OmctVakAD6lIcsULc7UqYi5ywFWnmEa3oUKwRXubX9ss5IV5VZ1LEj97NOq3OAInhFYbA97WowYf95rjAmV2G0vfwRRaAZE3lNX6xc) is something I might actually do or might've done already.

Comment: @KellyBundy: Eew. My opinion on comprehensions and genexprs (functional programming constructs) being intentionally used for side-effects (a distinctly non-functional thing to do) is unprintable. Don't get me wrong, I've written code like that for fun, but never for production code; if I needed "real" code like that, I'd expand it to the equivalent `for` loop with `if` checks, `break`s, etc. Sure, it's 4-5 lines instead of the 1-2 (depending on how you could the genexpr split across lines), but I don't feel dirty after writing it. :-)